# MSG Box display workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have an easy question but for whatever reason can´t find it online.  I want a msgbox to return me specific cells that apply to a set of conditions. For each cell I want it to say what workbook the cell is in.

```
MsgBox ("Error: " & cl.Address & " is " & cl.Value & " " & thisworkbook.Name)
```

is what I have in my code. What its returning is the name of the reporting workbook and not where the actual error is located.

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your situation you should go this way:

```
MsgBox ("Error: " & cl.Address & " is " & cl.Value & " " & cl.Parent.Parent.Name)
```

the final part will use hierarchy of Excel Object model- from Cell >> to Sheet >> to Workbook...